# Is there an algorithm to compute shortest tree (not path)?

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, shortest-path

Greetings Overflowers,

I have a weighted directed graph and I want the lowest cost tree that covers all nodes where the root is a specific given node of the graph. I do not know if I can also set a different maximum branching on each node where the number of branches from this node to other nodes (outward edges) is equal or less to that maximum ?

So what is the most suitable algorithm for my needs to start reading ? I hope it is fast enough :)

Many thanks !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for a directed minimum spanning tree (arborescence), which is an optimum branching.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu%E2%80%93Liu/Edmonds_algorithm

Comment: Thanks, that seems like it :) Any idea how to go about the maximum branching restriction ?

Comment: @geeko, I don't know off the top of my head how to implement it. I do know off the top of my head that it isn't a simple change (you can prove that quite easily). But I don't have a solution...